# localeurl with django1.5

Tags: django, internationalization, django-1.5

I migrated to django 1.5 and since I have a problem with `{% url "localeurl_change_locale"%}`.

In fact I have a form:

```
  <form id="ch_lg" method="POST" action="{% url "localeurl_change_locale" %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
      <select id="country-options" name="locale" onchange="$('#locale_switcher').submit()">
          {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
              <option value="{{ lang.0 }}" {% ifequal lang.0 LANGUAGE_CODE %}selected="selected"{% endifequal %}>{{ lang.1 }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
      </select>
      <noscript>
          <input type="submit" value="Set" />
      </noscript>
  </form>
```

It worked perfectly, but since the url change, I have a problem at the action `{% url "localeurl_change_locale"%}`.

After my research I don't understand what to do.
Thank you to you

Comment: What error? Give more details?

Comment: Here is what django returns : http://cl.ly/image/2g1u0Q2K3k24        If I don't put " as before django 1.5 and when it worked, it is obviously this error : http://cl.ly/image/3K3A0W1f2K2x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer ...
I didn't add

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
'/ path_project /',
)
```

in my settings.py

That'll teach me not to read carefully the new features.
If this post can help others with the same problem.